# Can someone identify this pistol grip tool?

Tags: identify-a-tool

Does anyone recognize this tool?

Maybe it came with a door or something and it is specific to that item?

[image]

Comment: Are there any markings on the metal or plastic bits? Can you give us a size reference?

Comment: Is the metal spike removable? Is it held in by a plasic barrel nut which can be loosened by turning CCW?

Comment: Looks a bit like a reamer, but it also looks like aluminum. Is it ferrous?

Comment: If it were a hex head, I'd almost think (based on your information that it may be related to a door) that it's used to lock open a crash bar on a commercial exterior door.  But in my experience those are typically hex keys.

Comment: It looks like a tool to remove/clean piercing holes in tires before sealing. Do not know english name of it

Comment: looks like something that someone made from another tool

Comment: @k_z, those typically have much more aggressive cuting teeth to shear rubber. This is much too smooth.

Comment: More info: Metal is aluminum. No markings. Not homemade as metal is fused into plastic grip. Four edges are defined but not sharp.  Too big to ream flat hole on regular tires. Came with the house we bought so probably specialty to unlock something with depth to reach hence the taper. Length I'd metal part is 1 1/16. Handle grip is 2 1/2 in long.